# Python "IndexError: list index out of range" error when the list item does exist

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.6

**The Problem:** When the code shown below is run from another part of my code (shown below this code) it produces an index error and says "list index out of range" when it clearly is not.

**The Code (Python Version 3.6.3):**

```
   def canwin(XoY):
        LookingForNum = True
        openspaces = []
        dupeboard = board[:]
        a = 0
        for i in range(9):
            if board[a] == " ":
                openspaces = openspaces + [a]
            a = a + 1
        a = 0
        for i in range(len(openspaces)):
                e = openspaces[a]
                dupeboard = [:]
                dupeboard[e] = XoY
                if dupeboard[0] == XoY and dupeboard[1] == XoY and dupeboard[2] == XoY:
                    return True
                elif dupeboard[3] == XoY and dupeboard[4] == XoY and dupeboard[5] == XoY:
                    return True
                elif dupeboard[6] == XoY and dupeboard[7] == XoY and dupeboard[8] == XoY:
                    return True
                elif dupeboard[0] == XoY and dupeboard[3] == XoY and dupeboard[6] == XoY:
                    return True
                elif dupeboard[1] == XoY and dupeboard[4] == XoY and dupeboard[7] == XoY:
                    return True
                elif dupeboard[2] == XoY and dupeboard[5] == XoY and dupeboard[8] == XoY:
                    return True

                elif dupeboard[0] == XoY and dupeboard[4] == XoY and dupeboard[8] == XoY:
                    return True
                elif dupeboard[2] == XoY and dupeboard[4] == XoY and dupeboard[6] == XoY:
                    return True
                else:
                    return False
                a = a + 1
```

**Running from:**

```
                if canwin("O"):
                    move = findmove("O")
                    board[move] = "O"
                    ShowBoard(board)
                    FindingNum = False

                elif canwin("X"):
                    move = findmove("X")
                    board[move] = "O"
                    ShowBoard(board)
                    FindingNum = False
```

**What I have tried:** I have tried checking the python documentation for index errors, and have had no luck with it. I have also checked out other stack overflow questions, and have had no luck.

**Full Traceback:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Pu\Testing Tic Tac Toe AI.py", line 316, in <module>
    PlayerPlay()
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Pu\Testing Tic Tac Toe AI.py", line 301, in PlayerPlay
    AIPlay(board)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Pu\Testing Tic Tac Toe AI.py", line 283, in AIPlay
    PlayerPlay()
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Pu\Testing Tic Tac Toe AI.py", line 301, in PlayerPlay
    AIPlay(board)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Pu\Testing Tic Tac Toe AI.py", line 283, in AIPlay
    PlayerPlay()
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Pu\Testing Tic Tac Toe AI.py", line 301, in PlayerPlay
    AIPlay(board)
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Pu\Testing Tic Tac Toe AI.py", line 259, in AIPlay
    if canwin("O"):
  File "C:\Users\user\Desktop\Pu\Testing Tic Tac Toe AI.py", line 70, in canwin
    elif dupeboard[2] == XoY and dupeboard[5] == XoY and dupeboard[8] == XoY:
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: check the size of `board` (`len`)  before accessing it

Comment: When you “dupeboard”, you left out `board[4]`. You should copy the list like this instead: `dupeboard = board[:]`

Comment: Following your advice, it still produces the error.

Comment: This time it is producing the error from line 70: elif dupeboard[2] == XoY and dupeboard[5] == XoY and dupeboard[8] == XoY:

Comment: Please post the complete Traceback, formatted as code.  Did you try to catch the error and print relevant data in the except suite? - what did you find. Or maybe just print just before the offending line. what happened?

Comment: The traceback is too long to post in a comment, and I can not print just before it since there are elif statements, meaning it will just bring up an error. I will post the traceback in multiple comments.

Comment: Edit your question and add the traceback. Do not post as several comments

Comment: `dupeboard = [board[0],board[1],board[2],board[3],board[5],board[6],board[7],board[8]]` Did you mean to leave out `board[4]`?

Comment: Forgot to change it there, only changed it in the first variable assignment.

Comment: `dupeboard = [:]` is wrong.

Comment: What is `board`: please include the result of `repr(board)` in your question, ...Please read [mcve]